What font was used in this poster's quote?
I tried all sources and tried to identify the font using "what the font" sites. But, not giving me any luck. Can the community help me find the font used in this poster?
I would really appreciate help identifying the font used in this image.


It looks like some variation of Boogaloo


This is indeed Boogaloo font. Thank you Luciano. I do not have much reputation to upvote, but I will do as soon as I get few.
